# Pandas column for count by date

Tags: pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that has a datetime index. I would like to add a column that holds the count of rows for the day.

```
dff = pd.DataFrame(['red','red','blue'],
    columns = ['colors'],
    index = [pd.Timestamp('2019-09-19 14:03:20'),pd.Timestamp('2019-09-19 17:03:20'),pd.Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:03:20')])

                    colors
2019-09-19 14:03:20 red
2019-09-19 17:03:20 red
2019-09-20 14:03:20 blue
```

So rows happening on 2019-09-19 should have a 'count' column of 2 and the last row a count column of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This temporarily creates a column with just the date, then counts said column and puts it into a new column called counts in the real data frame.

```
dff["counts"] = dff.assign(date_col = lambda x: x.index.date).groupby(['date_col']).transform('count')
```

Here's the whole thing to paste into an IDE and test:

```
import pandas as pd

dff = pd.DataFrame(['red','red','blue'],
    columns = ['colors'],
    index = [pd.Timestamp('2019-09-19 14:03:20'),pd.Timestamp('2019-09-19 17:03:20'),pd.Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:03:20')])

dff["counts"] = dff.assign(date_col = lambda x: x.index.date).groupby(['date_col']).transform('count')

print(dff)
```

And the result:

```
                        colors  counts
2019-09-19 14:03:20    red       2
2019-09-19 17:03:20    red       2
2019-09-20 14:03:20   blue       1
```